# como puedo poner el contenedor debajo del header?

Tags: html, css

Hola estoy comenzando con Html y Css y tengo una duda, el problema es que hice la barra de navegación y puse la imagen del header, mi intención es seguir con mas contenido debajo pero cuando intento seguir con una nueva sección se me posiciona todo encima del header, llevo un rato intentando editar código pero el error sigue igual, dejo un poco de html y css aqui para que puedan ver, también dejo una imagen de como se ve el contenido del parrafo: HOLA encima, si alguien puede ayudar lo agradecería mucho.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

````
 ``` <div class="contenedor">
        <main class="main">
            <h1>HOLA</h1>
        </main>
    </div> ```

```html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 62.5%; /*1rem = 10px*/
}
*, *:before, *:after{
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
body{
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   font-size: 1.6rem;
   line-height: 1.6;
   background: url(img/hero.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
   background-size: cover;
}

/*Globales*/

.contenedor{
    max-width: 120rem;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    min-height: 7vh;
    background-color: rgb(6, 100, 163)
}

/*Menu Responsive*/

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    body{
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .logo__imagen{
        padding-left: 25px;
    }  
}```
````

Comment: No se entiende bien lo que queres realizar, por favor detalla mas lo que deseas realizar y también pone el código completo porque con lo que pusiste no puedo hacer mucho para ayudarte.

Comment: cuando pongo el código completo me dice que hay mas código que explicación..... voy a volver a intentarlo

Comment: Quita la imagen y agrega el código completo con tal de poder hacer un duplicado de tu error. Si dice que falta explicación agrega algo con tal de completarlos, luego lo editamos fuera.